# Remove unwanted characters from specified column in all Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to remove some unwanted characters from a given column in all Worksheets from my Workbook. The code below works perfectly, but I'd like to know if there is a better/cleaner/faster way of doing this.

**What exactly am I doing?**
I am storing all unwanted/forbidden characters in an Array, after that I'm walking through all worksheets and replacing those characters with ""(empty) in each cell in column "J". In this case it will Always be in column J, but for maintainability (in case the template changes in future), I'm declaring it as a constant.

**Why do I need to do this?**
The data in this Workbook is uploaded to ALM, which does not allow any of those characters in the "Test Subject" field, hence I'm removing them. I chose this approach because I think it is easier, but if you have a better way of doing this (e.g. preventing the user from typing them in the first place, or any other approach that doesn't even require coding) it will be very welcome.

**Code:**

```
Sub replaceAll()

    Const FIRST_ROW As Integer = 2, TEST_COLUMN As String = "J"
    Dim arrForbidden() As String: arrForbidden = Split("\,/,:,%,',*,?,<,>,|,"",.", ",")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rngCells As Range
    Dim cell, character

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngCells = ws.Range(TEST_COLUMN & FIRST_ROW).Resize(lastRow - FIRST_ROW + 1, 1)

        For Each cell In rngCells
            For Each character In arrForbidden
                cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, character, "")
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post a new answer instead of editing the question if you want to share the new version.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Wow, many thanks for the reply and for the link. Great material

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let me note that your code looks good already. There are only a few things I would change:

1. It might be a good idea to turn the (Public) Sub into a Private Sub parameterized by `FIRST_ROW`, `TEST_COLUMN`, and `arrForbidden`, which then is called by a new Public Sub passing in your special values. This would separate the configuration from the actual algorithm.
2. The name of the sub and its parameters could be improved by replacing them with something more expressive, like `RemoveAllForbiddenCharacters` instead of `ReplaceAll`, and `removalColumn` instead of `TEST_COLUMN`. (Well, the last one is not very good, but nothing better came to my mind immediately.)
3. I am personally not a fan of declaring multiple variables on one line or initializing on the same line because it often hurts readability. However, here it does not really hurt.

Now, I would like to present a number of different approaches to your problem. Some of these can even be combined for better results.

### Using an Array to Query and Write Data

Instead of directly iterating over the cells in the collumn and updating every cell, you can read in the entire range into a two-dimensional (Variant) array using the `Value` property of the range, or even better the `Value2` property, which is faster and usually safer. (See this [blog post](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/).) 
Then, you can iterate over the array and finally paste it back by assigning to the `Value` property of the range.

This approach is faster then updating each cell because accessing the cells in a worksheet is rather slow.

### Using Regular Expressions

Instead of looping over your array, you could use a regular expression. The VBA support for these is in the library 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5'. An extensive description on how to use them can be found in [the answer to this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

Basically, what you would do is set up the regex matcher with a pattern string—in your case, `"[\\/:%'*?<>|"".]"`. Next, you would use the `Replace` function of the regex object to replace all occurrences of the forbidden characters in one go.

I do not know whether this is really much faster than the simple loop in your case. That pretty much depends on how well optimized the regex `Replace` procedure is. But either way, it is a little more expressive and you could reuse the code to do all sorts of more elaborate substitutions.

### Using User-Defined Functions

Instead of using a sub, you could write a function just for replacing all forbidden characters in a cell. Then, you could use this in some new column in the worksheets to automatically produce the cleaned-up version of your column in that new column. However, this would probably require you to actually reformat the worksheets before uploading to ALM (assuming ALM requires a fixed sheet layout for the import).

Personally, I do not really like this approach as it pollutes the worksheets with helper columns. However, if the need arises to remove the forbidden characters in more places, writing such a function might be the way to go.

### Using Excel Functions

If you do not want to use VBA at all, you can modify the previous approach to use a suitable Excel workbook function. The base function for this approach is `SUBSTITUTE`, which replaces occurrences of one string in another by a specified value.

A simple approach would be to nest calls to `SUBSTITUTE`, one for each character to replace. However, this very easily becomes completely unreadable. Moreover, there is an upper limit on how long a formula is allowed to be. (OK, [this Microsoft page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013) says the limit is now over 8000 characters, so this should not really be a problem.)

There might be a nicer way to reduce the nested formulas into one array formula, but I personally don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. As mentioned in Peter's answer, both of you provided great insight but since you provided the same answer as him with some additional tips, I decided to accept yours. The User Defined Functions and the Excel Functions won't work in my case, because as you pointed out (and as far as I know), ALM requires a fixed layout for the import. But working with the array, combining with the Regex, is the boost that I was looking for. Kudos

Answer (score 3):

Your code hits all the right notes for being short, easy to understand, and maintainable. I've seen far worse in production code. However, in the spirit of Code Review, here are a few comments:

1. In your first (double) declaration line, declaring the type of the `Const` is technically not necessary because VBA will assign a type from the value given. Additionally, you should separate the declarations into separate rows. You'd be surprised at how often having multiple declarations per line can trip you up later.
2. The only thing that running your code could encounter is execution time. Because you're pulling each cell from the worksheet inside of the double loop, the number of accesses directly to the worksheet `Cells` because geometric. You can greatly speed up your algorithm by copying the `Range.Column` to a memory-based array (see the `dataValues` variable and read [Work With Arrays, Not Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3830/work-with-arrays-not-with-ranges#t=20170110215514747052))

If your columns are particularly long, this should run faster:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceAll2()
    Const FIRST_ROW = 2
    Const TEST_COLUMN = "J"

    Dim arrForbidden() As String
    arrForbidden = Split("\,/,:,%,',*,?,<,>,|,"",.", ",")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rngCells As Range
    Dim dataValues As Variant
    Dim cell, character

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngCells = ws.Range(TEST_COLUMN & FIRST_ROW).Resize(lastRow - FIRST_ROW + 1, 1)

        '--- process the data in a memory array
        dataValues = rngCells

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(dataValues) To UBound(dataValues)
            For Each character In arrForbidden
                dataValues(i) = Replace(dataValues(i), character, "")
            Next
        Next

        '--- "Put the candle back!"   (bonus points if you know the quote)
        rngCells = dataValues
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback and the answer. Both you and M.Doerner provided great insight, but because I have to choose one answer to accept and because M.Doerner gave the same answer as you with a couple other alternatives for my approach (like the Regex one) I will accept his answer instead. Sorry about that (PS: I didn't know the quote until now, sorry about that either, but I did love the reference, though!). Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of both M.Doerner and PeterT's answers, this is how the code looks now. It is actually bigger than before, but it surely is faster (and hopefully more organized). The code is separated in a public Sub with only the configuration parameters and a call to a private Sub containing the actual code. The Array of forbidden strings is replaced with a RegExp pattern and the logic to work directly with Ranges is changed to work with an Array.

This is the working code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveAllForbiddenCharacters()

    Const FIRST_ROW = 2
    Const TARGET_COLUMN = "J"
    Const REGEX_PATTERN = "[\\/:%'*?<>|"".]"
    Const REGEX_REPLACE = ""

    Call RemoveCharactersWithRegExp(FIRST_ROW, TARGET_COLUMN, REGEX_PATTERN, REGEX_REPLACE)

End Sub

Private Sub RemoveCharactersWithRegExp(lngFirstRow As Long, strColumn As String, strPattern As String, strReplace As String)

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngCells As Range
    Dim dataValues As Variant

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, strColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngCells = ws.Range(strColumn & lngFirstRow).Resize(lngLastRow - lngFirstRow + 1, 1)
        dataValues = rngCells.Value2

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(dataValues) To UBound(dataValues)
            dataValues(i, 1) = regEx.Replace(dataValues(i, 1), strReplace)
        Next

        rngCells.Value2 = dataValues

    Next

End Sub
```